# how to show alert box button in vertical orientation in android?

Tags: android

I have one image button, when i click it opens 3 dialogbox buttons and they come in horizontal way. I want that alert dialog box button comes to vertical. How?

Answer (score 2):

try this simple method

```
public void verticalAlert (final String item01, final String item02, final String item03){

String[] array = {item01,item02,item03};
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
   builder.setTitle("Test")
          .setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // The 'which' argument contains the index position
              // of the selected item
                switch (which) {
            case 0:         
                // case item 1 do...
                break;          
            case 1:         
                //  case item 2 do...                   
                break;
            case 2:         
                //  case item 3 do...                   
                break;
            }

          }
   });
   builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to center the text in the dialog?

Your previous answer was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use View in the Alertdialog's setview method.
In that View,call the View's LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE and use a customized xml as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like a comment, answers with codes are more useful.